# Tomcat serving static content

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I have a Spring app and I'm wondering the best way to serve static content. I have tried the following:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works, but the behaviour of the DefaultServlet means that any request of the form `/static/PATH` serves the file from `webapp/PATH`. This exposes a massive vulnerability, allowing sensitive information to be shown with URLs such as: http://localhost/app/static/META-INF/context.xml

What's the common solution for this? Should I move the sensitive files? Write my own DefaultServlet? Or is there a better way to serve static content?

Comment: Don't you have a problem in your `context`, docBase for instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several better ways to serve static content.

**The traditional approach** was to use a [`UrlRewriteFilter`](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to remap URLs as follows:

`web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`urlrewrite.xml`:

```
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
    <rule>
        <from>/images/**</from>
        <to>/images/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/scripts/**</from>
        <to>/scripts/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/styles/**</from>
        <to>/styles/$1</to>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/**</from>
        <to>/app/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

This approach can be seen in the most of Spring samples.

---

Spring 3.0.1 introduced **a newer apporach** - it can serve static content via `DispatcherServlet`. It can be configured using `<mvc:resource>` element in Spring's config file. In Spring 3.0.4 it was extended with support of multiple location and cache control options, see [15.12.4 mvc:resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources).

Comment: @BalusC: Both described approaches solve this problem - the former by remapping `/*` to `/app/*` with explicit exclusions, the latter - by serving static content via `DispatcherServlet` mapped to `/`.

Comment: In my experience, Spring 3.0.4 is needed to recognize the `<mvc:resource>` tag (Not 3.0.1)

Answer (score 17):

Did you test it? The `/META-INF` and `/WEB-INF` folders are supposed to be public **inaccessible** as per the Servlet specification. The client should have gotten a 404 for this. It would otherwise have been a bug in `DefaultServlet`.

Here's an extract of [Servlet 2.5 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index2.html):

> #### SRV.9.5 Directory Structure
>
> ... Also, any
>   requests from the client to access the resources in `WEB-INF/` directory must be
>   returned with a `SC_NOT_FOUND(404)` response.

and

> #### SRV.9.6 Web Application Archive File
>
> ... Also, any requests to access the
>   resources in `META-INF` directory must be returned with a `SC_NOT_FOUND(404)`
>   response.

---

**Update**: OK, I take my words back. I can reproduce this on latest Tomcat 6 and 7. It's definitely a bug in `DefaultServlet`. It works fine (returns 404) on Glassfish 3.0.1.

---

**Update 2:** I've reported this to the Tomcat guys as [issue 50026](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50026).

---

**Update 3:** one of the Tomcat guys responsed as:

> I'm thinking this is a `WONTFIX`.
>
> The servlet engine protects the `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` paths in the web
>   application (which is working fine), not files of that name under arbitrary
>   paths.
>
> What's actually happening here is you're configuring a general purpose file
>   serving servlet to mount up your entire web application under a different path
>   - it's equivalent to configuring Apache to do the same thing. Except that
>   DefaultServlet isn't a general purpose file server - it's designed to be mapped
>   to `/`, and you can't configure it to do anything but serve files out of the web
>   application directory.
>
> I'm guessing you're trying to work around a problem introduced by mapping
>   another servlet to `/*`, which is basically trying to work around the way a
>   servlet engine works.
>   **[How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513)
>   has an example of a better way to approach things if this is what you're trying
>   to do.**
>
> Advice to remount `DefaultServlet` in Tomcat seems to have been around as long as
>   Tomcat has existed, so perhaps we need to lock it down (so people can't
>   accidentally create insecure configurations) or support mounting specific
>   directories (inside or outside the web application), and break if accessing the
>   root resources when mapped to a sub-path in any case.

---

**Update 4:** they've ultimately fixed it:

> Fixes for DefaultServlet and WebdavServlet are committed for 7.0.x (will be in
>   7.0.4+) and proposed for 6.0.x.
>   Will need to check 5.5.x and see if a backport is required for that too.

Comment: I did test it and I can see my context.xml clearly, with my database passwords inside.

Comment: Either you've placed the `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` folders in the wrong location (they must be placed in webcontent root, not in some subfolder like `/static`), or there's a bug in Tomcat version used.

Comment: Tomcat 6 actually works so. Even Spring's Petclinic sample is vulnerable https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/ Wow, just wow.

Comment: Just got a fresh Tomcat 6, a brand new Dynamic Web Project in eclipse and added just the following to `web.xml` and I can access META-INF:    <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: I take my words back, I can reproduce this. This is astonishing.

Answer (score 1):

`WEB-INF` and `META-INF` are private folders. The client must be getting 404 error for this. As `META_INF` contents are not accessible directly.Otherwise move all sensitive files in `WEB_INF`.