# spring SimpleUrlHandlerMapping to robots.txt

Tags: spring, url, robots.txt

I am using spring frameworking following is the mapping of url to controller

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
<props>
<prop key="/controller.web">webController</prop>
<prop key="/robots.txt">robotsController</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```

When i hit controller.web control gets to the web controller but when i hit robots.txt control do not transfer to the robotsController instead it tries to find out resource robots.txt if i remove robots.txt from context dir it says resource not found.

if i change robots.txt to robots.web it works fine it means there is some thing fishy with robots.txt's name any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `DispatcherServlet` is mapped as `<url-pattern>*.web</url-pattern>`, therefore it handles only requests to `*.web`.

If you want `DispatcherServlet` to handle request with different extensions you have several options:

- Add several `url-pattern`s to `<servlet-mapping>`:

  ```
  <url-pattern>*.web</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.txt</url-pattern>
  ```
- Handle all requests with `DispatcherServlet` mapped as `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`. Note that this approach requires some effort to serve static content, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822524/tomcat-serving-static-content/3823023#3823023).