# Access from internet the web.xml file of an applicaiton

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

Is it possible for someone to access or view the web.xml file of a web application over internet, using somthing like wget tool? I'm asking for saecurity reasons like username

Comment: as far as I know, it is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [specification](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340), it is not possible to directly access `/WEB-INF` (and `/META-INF`) contents by a public URL. Here are extracts of relevance from the aforelinked specification:

> ### 10.5 Directory structure
>
> ...
>
> Also, except
>   for the case where static resources are packaged in JAR files, any requests from the
>   client to access the resources in WEB-INF/ directory must be returned with a
>   SC_NOT_FOUND(404) response.

> ### 10.6 Web Application Archive File
>
> ...
>
> Also, any requests to access the resources in META-INF
>   directory must be returned with a SC_NOT_FOUND(404) response.

However, there have been implementations, configurations and even homegrown servlets or filters which introduced a security bug making this possible. All those security issues boil down to be caused by a [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) or even [`RequestDispatcher#include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) (so watch out with dynamic `<jsp:include>`!) call forwarding or including a resource which is specified by a client-controlled request path or parameter, if necessary making use of path traversal with `../`.

Here's the simplest example of such a servlet exposing the security issue:

```
@WebServlet("/test/*")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getPathInfo()).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

On Tomcat (tested with 8.0.21), you can with the above servlet get the `web.xml` contents by just calling `http://localhost:8080/context/test/WEB-INF/web.xml`. Such a servlet is often implemented as part of homegrown MVC front controller or dispatcher pattern. Decent MVC frameworks like JSF and Spring MVC shouldn't have this issue.

And, some users configure a MVC front controller on a "catch-all" URL pattern of `/*` or even `/`, and then re-map the static resources like CSS/JS/images on `/static/*` to container's `default` servlet like so:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

On older Tomcat versions (before 7.0.4), the enduser can get `/WEB-INF` (and `/META-INF`) contents through such a mapping. This problem was mentioned previously in this Q&A: [Tomcat serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822524/tomcat-serving-static-content). Actually, this mapping approach is wrong and should have been solved with help of a filter as descibed in this answer: [How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513). See also [Tomcat issue 50026](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50026).

Summarized: by default it's not possible. But (bad) code and configuration can make this possible.